# Is there too much policing on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I have thought of this question before but it struck me again this evening, when the system asked me to review a user's first question (Review Triage).

The question was in proper English and it was easy to understand what the user wanted, so I accepted it. I then realised that the question was a bogus or test question and should not be accepted, because the question itself was stupid. It raises two questions:

1. Why block questions?

   If a user asks a silly question, why not just ignore it? If one asks, in my opinion, a silly question, should I prevent another user from answering it? In my opinion no.

   Link spam, harassment, etc. in questions must be removed and bad English must be corrected. I think everybody can agree on that and that is not what I am talking about here.
2. Why this mistrust toward users who spend time on reviews?

Comment: For the review, what was the question? And are you asking why we should prevent bad questions?

Comment: _1. Why blocking questions?_ Because users need to contribute positively to the repository, if they fail at a certain rate to do so, they'll be first throttled, then blocked. _"2. Why this mistrust to user, who will spending some time on review?"_ Because it turned out that many reviewers do it in a _robotic_ fashion.

Comment: @Carcigenicate. Something about how to do a static html on alibaba. It was silly but the point is that user has the right to ask silly questions.

Comment: @AndersFinnJørgensen I think a link would be relevant because "stupid" isn't a good indicator. It's a question of whether or not it's ontopic, and that's not clear from your question. If it's not ontopic, it should be obvious why we shouldn't host it.

Comment: To answer your 2nd question, please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work.  In short, the gamification of reviews (with badges) led to enough users robotically clicking "Looks Ok" without actually reviewing the post that review audits were added to make sure users are paying attention.  And prevent users from reviewing who habitually fail audits

Comment: @TheDude I didn't do it in a robotic fashion. I just had an other opinion. If other opinions is not aloud here on SO, why ask us?

Comment: @AndersFinnJørgensen _“I didn't do it in a robotic fashion”_ — how do you expect the system to know this, other than auditing? If you disagree with an audit, explain why exactly.

Comment: @AndersFinnJørgensen Well, some of these audits are questionable, since they're picked up from the real life situations met here AFAIK, and the _communities_ behavior isn't always consistent how particular questions and answers are handled.

Comment: @Anders but, we can't just take your word for it here.... how do we test?

Comment: @AndersFinnJørgensen  `the point is that user has the right to ask silly questions` no, asking question on SO is a privilege not right. A privilege  can be revoked when certain standard are not met. And if you are not aware of those standards in SO, you shouldn't be doing any review.

Comment: No, not enough................

Comment: Ignoring questions is a pretty good strategy, provides the lowest odds that the user will come back to ask the next silly question.  It is just that this damn triage queue won't let you ignore it.  Ignore the queue, please.

Comment: >fails review miserably >why do you mistrust reviewers? >mfw I have no face

Comment: Both of these questions seem to be very much oriented from the idea that Stack Overflow is all about people. It is not, it is a knowledge base; the main purpose of this site is storing quality content. Silly questions are not quality content. The site does not mistrust reviewers, it demands that several reviewers look at things to minimise the chance of mistakes leading to the introduction of bad content or the loss of good content. Rather than try to educate people, they will be blocked if they do things wrong a few times. Why? *To protect the content*, it is not to punish.

Comment: @Gimby I'd argue pretty strongly that the site mistrusts reviewers.  In the past it had a decent amount of trust for them, and lots of people abused that trust, so *numerous* systems needed to be added to combat that abuse.  The mistrust is warranted, but it's certainly there.

Comment: @servy fair enough, that doesn't mean mistrust has to be assumed or advertised as the primary reason for the quality control systems to be in place.

Comment: @Gimby But if you were to ostensibly say that reviewers could be trusted to review properly then *those systems shouldn't be in place at all*.  The only good reason to have those systems is because reviewers *can't* be trusted, and they can't be.  What would you have the site do instead that would allow them to claim that reviewers are trustworthy, even though they aren't, and while still having numerous systems in place to catch bad reviewers?

Answer (score 21):

> Why block questions?

So that experts in their field can come to the site and find *high* quality *useful* questions, and provide their expertise in high quality and useful answers, rather than having their time wasted having to look through tons and tons of low quality questions that either can't be answered or won't be useful.

As a side effect, this also provides information to the question author on the problems with their question, so that they can address them and turn it into a *quality* question.

> Why this mistrust toward users who spend time on reviews?

Because they've been shown to not be trustworthy.  Time, and time, and time again, we see people doing a bad job of reviewing, and making the site *worse* as a consequence.  Yes, reviewing is optional, it's an entirely voluntary activity.  You aren't obligated to help curate the site if you don't want to, but if you *are* going to, you are expected to do so properly.

> If a user asks a silly question, why not just ignore it? If one asks, in my opinion, a silly question, should I prevent another user from answering it? In my opinion no.

And why do you think adding low quality questions with low quality answers that won't be helpful to other people is a good thing?  It's been shown that SO's tools for curating content have been *very* successful at improving posts' quality, and that it makes it a much more useful resource to the programming community as a result.  You've stated, without evidence, that you don't like it, despite *considerable* evidence suggesting that your approach is not nearly as useful.  There are *lots* of QA sites out there that subscribe to your model of allowing everything.  They create *far* less useful content.  If you want to participate in a site that doesn't have quality standards, that's fine, there are *lots* of them out there.  This just isn't one of them.

Comment: Allowing such questions would be like free beer to the puppeteers and voting-rings.